# MVC - using enum in the DisplayAttribute of a Model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

My questions is: I have an enum class as:

```
public enum EnumApplications
{       
    Android = 1,        
    IOS = 2
}
```

Also I have a Model which is for Creating a new user. a user can be defined as Active in any of these application when we create a new user.

My model is:

```
public class NewUserModel
{

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Is Active in IOS")]
    public bool IsActiveInApp1 { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Is Active in Android")]
    public bool IsActiveInApp2 { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is in the:  `[Display(Name = "Is Active in Android")]`

I want to use the enum so if the app name gets changed I don't need to change it here, something like:

```
EnumApplications.IOS.ToString()
```

Here's a screenshot for better understanding:

Comment: You can't do that. Unless you create your own custom DisplayAttribute, which doesn't make any sense. Just use the enum in your View.

Comment: you're attempt to do what exactly?.. embed instance data in an attribute?

Comment: make sense, thank you

Comment: @Brett , embed enum in display attr

Comment: embed the enum, or an instance's enum value?

Comment: @Brett, what I want is in my model instead of saying [Display(Name = "Is Active in IOS")] and hardcoding IOS. I want to get the name of IOS from my enum. so if we decide to change the name, we change it in enum once

Comment: What if you want to add a new app to the enum? You should be more concerned about that than changing the name of an app.

Comment: I would use an `IEnumerable<bool>` property instead of two bool properties for the two apps in the enum.

Comment: @ataravati that's pretty ambigious.. I'm not sure what that would accomplish

Comment: I don't know all the details about the requirements, but I wouldn't even use an enum for the apps. I would use a database table. Otherwise, every time he needs to add a new app, he'll have to add a new property to his user model.

Comment: @erfan "we change it in enum once".. and then refactor, you mean... unless it's some sort of T4 templating going on here..

Comment: @ataravati  you are right, db would be the right approach, I agree, it is just that part I cant change. thanks for your suggestion though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I want to use the enum so if the app name gets changed I don't need to change it here"

No, there is no easy way to do this.

the only implementation I can think of (aside from runtime assembly/type compiling and generation) that you could do that, is a T4 template. the template would generate the model, and you would have to run it after modifying your `enum`.

---

in regards to your question title and comment:

> MVC - Using Enum In The DisplayAttribute of a Model class
>
> what I want is in my model instead of saying [Display(Name = "Is Active in IOS")] and hardcoding IOS. I want to get the name of IOS from my enum.

The following solution (which isn't T4 or Runtime compiling) just inherits `DisplayNameAttribute` and uses the constructor of your type to pass the parameter to the base type.

It is a solution in the sense that if you were to change `Android` to `Andy` you would use a refactor tool ( built-in intellisense tool these days) to implement that change across code files that references that value type.

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    NotSet = 0,
    iOS = 1,
    Android = 2
}

class MyDisplayNameAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public MyDisplayNameAttribute(MyEnum myEnum)
        : base("Is Active in " + myEnum.ToString())
    { 

    }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            // you could do the "Is Active in " here, but I doubt control frameworks would use it.
            return base.DisplayName;                
        }
    }         
}

public class MyModel
{
    [MyDisplayName(MyEnum.iOS)]
    bool IsActiveApp1 { get; set; }

    // uses standard 'DisplayNameAttribute' type for test below
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Is Active in Android")]
    bool IsActiveApp2 { get; set; }
}
```

For quick testing, we'll do what control frameworks do, reflect over the provided type and get the CustomAttribute.. note that there is more type checking involved, we'll casting it to `DisplayNameAttribute` for brevity.

```
string[] PropertyNames = new string[] { "IsActiveApp1", "IsActiveApp2" };
System.Type MyModelInfo = typeof(MyModel);
       
PropertyNames.SelectMany(prop => MyModelInfo.GetProperty(prop).GetCustomAttributes(true))
    .ToList().ForEach((attr) =>
        {
             Console.WriteLine(((System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute)attr).DisplayName);
        });
```

Comment: I think OP needs to get the application name inside customer attribute  dynamically from db/session or wherever it is stored. Otherwise why can't he directly put some `const` (constant) and get the work done?

Comment: @SivaGopal perhaps the values are populated from db/session or whatever.. but that doesn't really have anything to do with how the name is displayed by a control..

Comment: the purpose of the OP, as he explained it in comments.. it to do DisplayName("Is Active in " + Enum) vs DisplayName("Is Active in <Value>") .. it is a pre-compilation concern.. and it doesn't depict the value of the property.. just associates the property to a display name